# Ezpolar plots function string over polar axes

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I'm using [Ezpolar](http://es.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/ezpolar.html) function in order to plot some graphics. Three of them have as maximum value 4, but the last one only has a bit more than 2.

When I plot them, the last one is plotted with it's function over it (seems like if `ezpolar` paints it some pixels after it maxium value used as radius).

### Code and Generated Plot

```
% This subplot is used since I've 4 graphics to draw.
subplot(2,2,4)
ezpolar('0.25*(5 - 4*cosd(-180 * sin(t) ))');
title('D')
```

If I don't use this subplot, using a complete `figure` to draw the graphics **seems fine**. However, since I need to have all four of them together, it results in (will draw only the problematic one, `subplot 2,2,4`):

[image: Image plotted]

As you can see, `r = 0.25 (5 - 4...)` **is plotted just over the polar axes**.

Why is it happening? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue appears to be with the position of that annotation and the fact that when you use a `subplot`, the limits on the radius of the polar plot actually change but the position of the annotation *does not*.

To combat this, you could actually compute the limits of the axes and change the position of the text to be explicitly outside of the plot.

```
hax = subplot(2,2,4);
p = ezpolar('0.25*(5 - 4*cosd(-180 * sin(t) ))');

% Get the handle to the label text object
label = findobj(hax, 'type', 'text');

% Figure out the current axes limits
ylims = get(hax, 'ylim');

% Add some padding (as a percent) to the position
padding = 0.2;
set(label, 'Position', [0 ylims(1)*(1 + padding), 0]);
```

[image]

A better way to do this would be to change the `Units` of the label to use `Normalized` units (relative to the axes) rather than `Data` units. This way, it will not change if the axes limits change.

```
hax = subplot(2,2,4);
p = ezpolar('0.25*(5 - 4*cosd(-180 * sin(t) ))');

% Get the handle to the label text object
label = findobj(hax, 'type', 'text');

set(label, 'Units', 'Normalized', 'Position', [0.5, -0.2]);
```